# L6203 H bridge (very) high Rds on

Tags: motor, driver

datasheet: [L6203 DMOS FULL BRIDGE DRIVER](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/03/af/9d/d5/a2/56/46/f6/CD00000089.pdf/files/CD00000089.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000089.pdf)

I was testing this H bridge on wire wound high power resistors. I have noticed a high drop in the output voltage. The measurements taken are as follow:

Vin=13V;
Vout=9V;
Iout=2.7A
=>Rds=1.48 Ohms

Vin=12.8V;
Vout=8.7V;
Iout=2.46
=>Rds=1.6 Ohms

Vin=15.2V;
Vout=10.8V;
Iout=3A
=>Rds=1.46 Ohms

Vin=17V;
Vout=11V;
Iout=3.3A
=>Rds=1.8 Ohms

Vin=20V;
Vout-19V;
Iout=0.56A
=>Rds=1.78 Ohms

Ofcource some of the test where done where the Driver was really Hot (near 140 C as measured by an infrared Thermometer) so here is the temperature Derating:

[image: Rds on as a function of temperature]

Also There is another curve that describes the variation of the supply voltage
:

[image: Rds on as a function of supply voltage]

The curves implies that Rds on should never reach higher 0.8 Ohms (suppose derating due to temperature = 2 @ 150C)

Tests I also tried:

- Use of a [demo board](http://www.thanksbuyer.com/mini-ibt-arduino-hollow-cup-motor-driver-module-h-bridge-12-48v-5a-strong-braking-30158) that uses the same chip but SMD footprint. Almost identical results
- Use of 99% duty cycle signal instead of a constant DC signal at the PWM inputs of the driver (maybe charge pump needs that). Same results
- Use of 5V logic instead of 3.3V logic for PWM and enable signal... Same results.
- Trying to drive a motor instead of series wound resistors. Same results.
- Removed snubber/schottcky diodes at output. Same results
- Buy drivers from a different supplier to make sure that the driver isn't a counterfeit component(I didn't trust the supplier).Same results.

All measurements are taken using a true RMS multimeter. Vin is the voltage between GND and VS. Vout is between OUT1 and OUT2. I am measuring exactly at the pins so no drops are present because of the PCB/wiring.

circuit:

[image: Schematic]

Question is obvious: WHAT THE HELL IS GOING ON? The efficiency is crap and the driver is overheating quickly. I'm using a very large heatsink, still, the driver is unable to drive more than 2A continuous!! What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What is the voltage?

Comment: By the way, the input capacitor is very small. Should be tens or hundreds of microfarads

Comment: What Cboot capacitors are you using?

Comment: voltage is Vin of each experiment. That is 12 .8V,13V,15.2V...etc

Comment: I placed 200uF-50V very close to the IC (not seen in schematic) along with a 220uF at the input of the switching regulator I am using to power the Logic and microcontroller. so total capacitance is 420uF. I used aluminum  caps

Comment: Cboot capacitors are ceramic capacitors rated at 50V.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that Rds-on here is (per leg) so you need to multiply it by 2 to compare it with delta(V)/I.
Many integrated H-bridge IC specify the Rds-on for the high side FET and for the low side FET. Take for example this [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1b/41/37/d4/6d/b3/42/ee/DM00040392.pdf/files/DM00040392.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00040392.pdf).

Returning to the definition for Rds-on, it is easy to see why and to expect this.