# L6203 motor driver with high Rds(on)

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge

The L6203 states that it typically has and Rds(on) of about 0.3 ohm. After implementing the circuit below, I'm measuring a significant voltage drop across the transistors when the motor is stalled (or with increased current). The results correspond to a Rds(on) between 1.5 and 2 ohm. I'm using a supply voltage of 17 V.

This is much greater than the value indicated on the front page of the [datasheet](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Datasheets/L6203.pdf) of 0.3 ohm. Furthermore, the device is labelled on the datasheet as being "High Efficiency". The only conclusion that I can make is that I may be missing something important. My problem/results are very similar to a previous [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268284/l6203-h-bridge-very-high-rds-on#) which was never fully resolved. I'm hoping someone could offer some new insight?

[image]

**Edit**

Here is some more data. The circuit is as shown above with a 1uF capacitor between Vs and gnd.

- Load is a 5 ohm motor at stall
- Supply voltage (after series multimeter measuring supply current) = 15.8V
- EN = high
- V_IN1 = 5V PWM at 80% duty
- V_IN2 = gnd
- Total current draw from supply = 1.6A
- V_OUT1 = 1.8V
- V_OUT2 = 9.6V
- The chip is at room temperature for these measurements

If the load is removed then output waveform swings to the rails as expected. These results seem to indicate a much larger Rds(on) than 0.3 ohm as stated by the datasheet.

Comment: What current is the motor taking?

Comment: Supply voltage is 17V, motor resistance is 5 ohm. I'm struggling to get anything over 2A. That is without switching, just operating with one input high and the other low.

Comment: How are you powering your circuit? Because if you go to page 5 of the datasheet, and see the Vs/Rdson curve, they show the correlation between Rdson and the supply voltage Vs. If the stalled motor is consuming too much current, it might be that the voltage of your power supply is dropping, increasing significantly the Rdson

Comment: I'm afraid it's not the supply. 2-5A is no problem for my supply :)

Comment: You need to show actual, at-the-same-time measurements of current with voltage across both the high and low side drivers and overall supply voltage if you want help.  Don't ask people here to join you in your assumptions, provide *actual measurements* of each required detail.

Comment: @chrisStratton As I have indicated, my problem is very similar to the one that I linked, although there was no good explanation for what was happening. It is obvious from my measurements that voltage across my motor is dropping fairly quickly with increased current. All that can explain this is a large Rds of the transistors - although that is not consistent with the datasheet. I have posted the circuit that I am using. Unfortunately I have a very crude oscilloscope and am not able to give you the other measurements requested. My question is simply, is the behavior that I am seeing expected?

Comment: How hot does the L6203 become? RDS (ON) 0.3\$ \Omega \$ **(typical value at 25 °C)**, probably with a big copper area.

Comment: All you need is a voltmeter.  Unless you are willing to provide specific measurements, there is no reason this should not be closed as a duplicate of the existing question - any eventual answer can go there as readily as here, and having two questions about the same problem (even if experienced by different people) is not how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: I can't find it in the the datasheet at the moment, but a lot of drivers that have a high-side charge pump won't work right if you hold the high-side on solid -- there's some minimum off period and maximum on period that you have to observe, or the high-side gate won't be held above the supply voltage.  You might want to dig through the datasheet, or do the experiment of driving the thing with just a bit of PWM and see if that helps.

Comment: I have updated my results to include a duty cycle of 80%. Unfortunately no improvement

Comment: Could you please provide a picture of the components layout or a PCB layout?